# Grabar tiempo de escritura de textos

Tags: javascript, html, html5, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

cuento con una duda, debo realizar con **JavaScript o ASP. NetFramework** que permita **grabar el tiempo** que me demoro escribiendo un texto y que posterior permita **reproducir la escritura o subrayado del texto escrito en el mismo tiempo** que se tardó en escribirse.

```
// iniciar funcion
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var tiempoescritura;
          // iniciamos el timer
          $("#escribir").keyup(function(e) {
              clearTimeout(tiempoescritura);
              if (e.keyCode == 13){ // Si se presiona enter no se ejecutará la función
              return true;
              }
          // he puesto 1s, podrías poner el valor que quieras
          tiempoescritura = setTimeout(mostrarproductos, 1000);
      });
      // borramos el timer
      $("#escribir").keydown(function() {
          clearTimeout(tiempoescritura);
      });
      function mostrarproductos(){
        console.log("He dejado de escribir!");
      }
  });

  <textarea id="escribir" name="escibir"></textarea>
```

Comment: y que has intentado, que código llevas hasta ahora?

Comment: Hasta el momento solo he realizado cuando escribo me marca que dejé de escribir

Comment: por favor agrégalo a la pregunta, por que sino parece que quieres que te hagan el programa

Comment: Ahí agregue el código, lo que no sabría es como guardar el tiempo que tardo en escribir.